# How to get around permission denied error when editing /etc/systemd/system.conf

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions

I am trying to update `/etc/systemd/system.conf` with

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536
```

using nano but I am unable to and get the error:

```
[error writing /etc/systemd/system.conf Permission denied]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/system/system.conf` is a system file, and in order to edit it you'll need **root** permissions.

If you know the root password of the system (that's not your user's password) you can open the file for editing using:

```
su -c 'nano /etc/system/system.conf'
```

And enter the root user's password when asked.

If your user was set up to have access to `nano` with `sudo`, you can use:

```
sudo nano /etc/system/system.conf
```

And enter your user password when asked for password.

Once you have the file open this way you can edit and then save the modified one.